# Laravel Scout import existing data don't work

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

there,

I installed Laravel Scout. If I now create a new record it will be imported correctly into Algolia. Editing and deleting also works.
But now I want to import all existing organizations. 
When I run the command:

```
$ php artisan scout:import "App\Models\Organisation\Organisation"
All [App\Models\Organisation\Organisation] records have been imported.
```

However, no organizations are written to the index. Do I still have to specify anything somewhere?

Comment: Do you add `Searchable` trait to your Organistaion model?

Comment: @bl4cksta yess au added this: 
`class Organisation extends Model
{
    public static $autoIndex = false;
    public static $autoDelete = false;
    
    use OrganisationRelationship,
     OrganisationAttribute,
        Notifiable,
        Searchable,
        Sluggable,
        SluggableScopeHelpers;
`

Answer (score 0):

did you set `'driver' => env('SCOUT_DRIVER', 'algolia'),` in published `scout.php` file ?
tips : try meilisearch , has a good doc than **algolia**